# spacing in the table's minipage

Tags: minipage, line-spacing, setspace

In my thesis I have a lot of tables and some of them have a minipage for notes. For all thesis I'm using 1.5 in spacing. For this I'm using `\linespread{1.5}`. But I don't want the same spacing for minipage into the tables. That is, for the minipage inside the table should have 1.0 in spacing. How can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you please add a full  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Have you considered not using `\linespread` at all, and instead loading the `setspace` package and executing the instruction `\setstretch{1.5}`? This alternative approach should give you what you need, in terms of automatically getting single-spacing in minipages.

Comment: You should consider using `setspace`.

Comment: If you really want to use `\linespread` directly, just put `\linespread{1.0}\selectfont` inside the minipage. But it's much easier to use `setspace` package.

Comment: @Mico I will never understand, why people pack their answers into a comment and deny the OP accepting the answer. How many readers will look into this »unanswered« question again and again, only to find, that you burried the answer in a comment field!

Comment: @KeksDose - Since the OP hadn't posted an MWE, I thought there was a reasonable chance that taking my suggestion, i.e., loading the `setspace` package and executing `\setstretch{1.5}` instead of using the rather low-level `\linespread` instruction, was not going to get the job done. I was pleasantly surprised when the OP informed me that the suggestion worked fine. I will, of course, be happy to re-post my suggestion as an official answer if the OP asks me to do so.

Comment: @Mico Oh Lord, just do it.

Comment: @KeksDose - Done. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(this is a slightly expanded version of my earlier comment)

Don't use the fairly low-level `\linespread` command to change from single-spacing to, say, one-and-one-half-spacing. As you've discovered, it affects not only the main body of the text but also the material inside minipages, tabular and array environments, footnotes, and so on.

Instead, load the [setspace](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/setspace) package (ideally with the option `nodisplayskipstretch`) and then execute the package's `\setstretch` command, say, `\setstretch{1.5}`.

```
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
```

The `setspace` package also offers macros with fairly descriptive names --`\singlespacing` (equivalent to `\setstretch {1.0}`), `\onehalfspacing`, and `\doublespacing` -- as well as environments with these names.

Comment: For me this results in an `Option clash for package setspace. \setstretch` error. Removing the `nodisplayskipstretch` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237291/160825) it is possible to use `linespread` inside parboxes, minipages and so on. Just remember to add a `\selectfont` directly after the line spacing change.

```
\begin{minipage}
\linespread{1.0}\selectfont
Your Minipage inside your table
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, either with or without `\selectfont`. I don't expect that to make any difference, but I'm using the Minipage by itself, not inside a table.