# Custom linespacing in a parbox

Tags: macros, boxes, line-spacing

Is there a way to set the line spacing into a `\parbox`?

What I am trying to do is create a new command from a `\rotatebox` and `\parbox`
and assign *locally*, i. e. only inside of the `\parbox`, custom line spacing.

It should look similar to this one:

```
\newcommand{\crazybox}[2]{\rotatebox{60}{\parbox{30mm}{\magicLineSpacingCommand{#1} \raggedright \textit{#2}}}}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any of the normal commands to set line spacing will work in a parbox, for example

```
\parbox{\linewidth}{\linespread{2}\selectfont....}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the the `\selectfont{}` part.

Comment: If you are using `\parbox` with two sets of `{}` like `\parbox{\linewidth}{Lorem ipsum}` remember to put the suggested code directly in the parbox content and *not* in the first one: `\parbox{\linewidth}{\linespread{1}\selectfont Lorem ipsum}`

Comment: @mhellmeier what you meant to say (but were too polite:-) is that the example code in this answer is completely wrong (despite 12 votes and a green tick) I'll fix thanks!